# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Не понимаю как исправить код, чтобы все заработало? Выдает эту ошибку: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def spin():
    v=0
    if v.get()<10:
        v='0'+str(v.get())
    elif v.get()>9:
        v=str(v.get())


root=Tk()
root.title("Нумерация")
v=IntVar()

mes=Label(root,text='Выберите месяц')
mes.pack()
mes_1=Spinbox(root, textvariable=v, from_=1, to=12, command=spin)
mes_1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А что должен сделать скрипт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У числа нет метода `get()`, который вы пытаетесь выполнить. Исправить нужно так:

```
if v < 10:
    v = '0'+str(v)
else:
    v = str(v)
```

А учитывая, что прямо перед этим вы присваиваете v = 0, то можно все сократить до

```
def spin():
    v = "00"
```

---

**Второй вариант (то, что вам на самом деле нужно):**

```
mes_1=Spinbox(root, values=("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06" и т.д.))
```

А функцию `spin()` вообще удалить.

Comment: Мне кажется странным что сначала v это число, а потом строка.

Comment: @coder675 Что в этом странного?